# PHP Get Rendered Javascript Page

Tags: javascript, php, angularjs, ajax

I'm developing application using AngularJS. Everything seems to be nice until I meet something that leads me to headache: SEO.

From many references, I found out that AJAX content crawled and indexed by Google bot or Bing bot 'is not that easy' since the crawlers don't render Javascript.

Currently I need a solution using PHP. I use PHP Slim Framework so my main file is index.php which contains function to echo the content of my index.html. My question is:

**Is it possible to make a snapshot of rendered Javascript in HTML?**

My strategy is:

*If the request query string contains _escaped_fragment_, the application will generate a snapshot and give that snapshot as response instead of the exact file.*

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After plenty of times searching and researching, I finally managed to solve my problem by mixing PHP with PhantomJS (version 2.0). I use exec() function in PHP to run phantomJS and create Javascript file to take get the content of the targeted URL. Here are the snippets:

**index.php**

```
// Let's assume that you have a bin folder under your root folder directory which contains phantomjs.exe and content.js
$script = __DIR__ ."/bin/content.js";
$target = "http://www.kincir.com"; // target URL
$cmd = __DIR__."/bin/phantomjs.exe $script $target";
exec($cmd, $output);
return implode("", $output);
```

**content.js**

```
var webPage = require('webpage');
var system = require('system');
var page = webPage.create();
var url = system.args[1]; // This will get the second argument from $cmd, in this example, it will be the value of $target on index.php which is "http://www.kincir.com" 
page.open(url, function (status) {
  page.onLoadFinished = function () { // Make sure to return the content of the page once the page is finish loaded
      var content = page.content;
      console.log(content);
      phantom.exit();
  };
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I recently published a project that gives PHP access to a browser. Get it here: https://github.com/merlinthemagic/MTS. It also relies on PhantomJS.

After downloading and setup you would simply use the following code:

```
$myUrl          = "http://www.example.com";
$windowObj      = \MTS\Factories::getDevices()->getLocalHost()->getBrowser('phantomjs')->getNewWindow($myUrl);

//now you can either retrive the DOM and parse it, like this:
$domData    = $windowObj->getDom();

//this project also lets you manipulate the live page. Click, fill forms, submit etc.
```

Comment: Hi, @Merlin! Nice project, Man. I will take a look at it. Thanks.

Comment: Just noticed your solution uses .exe for phantomJS. Sorry the tools are Linux only. Come over to the dark side :)

Comment: Actually, I'm also looking for the tools for Linux since I'm planning to use it in the future.. :)

Comment: @asubanovsky Just added support for windows, if you still need it.