# PHP: Fetch remote page AFTER JS events have loaded

Tags: php

I'm using a simple method of loading a remote webpage that works fine mostly:

```
$output = file_get_contents($item['URL']);
$html->loadHTML($output);
```

After which I can search for tags by type or name or ID, but the problem is that the main content I want is generated after the fact by JS in the last second. When loading in a browser, you don't notice it, but when trying to get it with file_get_contents, I get the page as it exists before the last minute JS runs.

Here's the partial code that loads what I want so you can see what I mean, but it's pretty straighforward: the page I get isn't the "complete" page.

```
<script type="text/javascript">ImageMachine.prototype.ImageMachine_Generate_Thumbnail = function (thumbnail_image, main_image, closeup_image, type_code) {
var thumbnail,
img;
```

I tried using CURL too, but no luck.

```
                $header[] = "Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,;q=0.8";
                $header[] = "Connection: keep-alive";

                $ch = curl_init();
                curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $item['URL']);
                curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $header_str);
//              curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);
                curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIE, true); 
                curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true); 
//              curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
                curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_ENCODING, '');         
                curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
                curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, $this_time);
                $output = curl_exec($ch);
                curl_close($ch);
                    
                @$html->loadHTML($output);
```

Is there a way to get the whole thing? I want the same page a browser or user would see if they load the page.

Comment: The way web pages work is that first the page (HTML) is downloaded, then the browser starts from the top and renders the page, downloading and running JavaScript/CSS files as it reaches them.  In your case, you've done the first part, and downloaded the HTML, but you are not rendering it.  You just have the HTML as the server delivers, and that's it.  You'll need to use another tool/library to actually render the page and then get the info you are after.

Comment: Is there such a tool or method?

Comment: You can try something like PhantomJS.  I haven't tried it, but maybe something like http://jonnnnyw.github.io/php-phantomjs/

Comment: What you need to look for is a "headless browser" that you can run via PHP.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [PHP Get Rendered Javascript Page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34129845/php-get-rendered-javascript-page)

Comment: It's along the right lines, but I won't be able to install Phantom on my hosting service.